# Modeless dialog in ExtJs

Tags: extjs, modeless

I want to implement modeless dialog boxes in ExtJS.

For exapmle, the new pop-up window/panel should not leave the originating screen as inactive. Both should be accessible at the same time.

How do we that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modal option on Ext.Window defaults to false, so just don't include that option and the dialogs won't be modal.

Comment: Is it applicable to Panels also?